# Can anyone please help me to solve this error , this error came up after I installed angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js:4:0-102 -Error: **export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)**

./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js:11:0-75 - **Error: export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)**
./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:16:0-75 - **Error: export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)**

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far ? Maybe try removing the node_modules folder and run "npm install"

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes . I tried that too ,still facing the same issue.

Comment: Do you import it like "import { detectOverflow } from '@popperjs/core';" ?

Comment: Yes.This didn't resolve the error.

Comment: Okay. Please make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can try fixing it

Comment: Perhaps import { detectOverflow } from '@popperjs/core/lib/popper'; https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/issues/1130

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the file

node_modules@popperjs\core\lib\createPopper.js

try this one:

```
import { detectOverflow } from '@popperjs/core;
```

insted of this:

```
import detectOverflow from "./utils/detectOverflow.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was from using the sveltestrap package, hopefully one of these solutions will work for you.

[Multiple solutions here](https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap/issues/463)

The one that worked for me was adding

```
"type": "module",
```

right above the "devDependencies" property in nodemodules/@popperjs/core/package.json

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm install` fixed it for me. I think there were old dependencies getting loaded when they shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting both your `package-lock.json` file and your `node_modules` folder.
For me, it got fixed only after I deleted my `package-lock` file and did a fresh `npm i`.